# using if and else to check directory name and assign variable in linux bash script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, variables, directory

I am creating (what I thought was) a simple script to check through my current directory which contains more directories with the names;

```
SAMPLE_ANN-A10, SAMPLE_ANN-B4 etc.
SAMPLE_NEM-E7, SAMPLE_NEM-H2, etc.
SAMPLE_TODE-H02 etc. etc.
```

I would like to assign a QUERY variable for each SAMPLE and run a command. All TODEs will use the same variable, all NEMs will use the same and all ANNs the same.

Here is my current script with the error message. Thanks for looking.

---

```
#!/bin/bash

for dir in $@
do
QUERY=''
    if $dir == SAMPLE_ANN*/
        then
            $QUERY=annelids.fasta
    elif $dir == SAMPLE_NEM*/
        then
            $QUERY=nemertea.fasta
    else
        $QUERY=nematode.fasta
    fi

    echo $QUERY #used to check if the variable was set correctly

nohup blastn -query $QUERY -subject $dir/spades_output/contigs.fasta -out $dir/spades_output/mito_blast

done
```

---

```
#command from linux --> ./auto_mito_blast.sh SAMPLE_ANN-B4
```

---

```
#error message : 

#./auto_mito_blast.sh: line 7: Sample_ANN-B4/: Is a directory
#./auto_mito_blast.sh: line 10: Sample_ANN-B4/: Is a directory
#./auto_mito_blast.sh: line 14: =nematode.fasta: command not found
```

Thanks,
Joe

Comment: The problem is that `if` tests the exit code of the command that follows it; it is trying to run `$dir` (whatever that value happens to be) as a command, with parameters `==` and the expansion of the shell glob `SAMPLE_ANN*/`. What you need is to use the program `test`, which is /bin/test or a shell builtin, or the alias for test, `[` (/bin/[ or builtin) or, as SleepProgger does, use the _bash_ "keyword" `[[` (note that **[[** is non-portable, but that's usually not an issue these days since bash is in wide use.)

Answer (score 0):

Double brackets *[[* should do the work. =>

```
for dir in $@
do
    QUERY=''
    if [[ $dir == SAMPLE_ANN* ]]
        then
            QUERY=annelids.fasta
    elif [[ $dir == SAMPLE_NEM* ]]
        then
            QUERY=nemertea.fasta
    else
        QUERY=nematode.fasta
    fi
    echo $QUERY #used to check if the variable was set correctly
done
```

ATM: you are just iterating over all given parameter, but as far as i understand you want to iterate over all directories in the current directory, which would be something like:

```
for dir in ./*
```

Still need some *is dir* check.
Another way would be using find like

```
find . -type d -depth 1 --execute yourscript {} \;
```

Comment: `find . -type d` will find _all_ directories under the current directory. To find only the directories **_in_** the current dir use the _depth_ parameter: `find . -type d -depth 1 --execute ...`

Comment: @StephenP Thanks. Updated the answer.